# Printing empty Pyramid

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I want to write a program that prints this output:

```
   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *
   *
```

But it prints this instead:

```
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Suppose *n* = 5 is the input from the user, then the first star should be in the centre, and the ending star as well, so I can divide the input number by 2 to get the position of the first and the last star.

For the rest of the stars I am not understanding how to make it so that if one star is above then the next star should not be below it.

```
def Empty_triangle(n): 
    k = 2*n - 2
    for i in range(0, n): 
        for j in range(0, k): 
            print(end=" ")

        k = k - 1

        for j in range(0, i+1): 
            # printing stars 
            print("* ", end="") 

        # ending line after each row 
        print("\r") 

# Driver Code 
n = 5
Empty_triangle(n)
```

Comment: `I wrote the code` ... but you never posted the code you wrote.

Comment: you wrote the code but we can't see it (could you add it please?)

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this sort of thing?

```
print("\n".join([" "*(n-2-i)+"*"+" "*(2*i-1)+("*"if i>0 else"") for i in list(range(n-1))+[0]]))
```

Which, for example, for n=5, gives this output:

```
   *
  * *
 *   *
*     *
   *
```

Is this the kind of thing you had in mind?

Here's a less code-golfish version

```
def Empty_triangle(n): 
    for i in list(range(n-1))+[0]: #i.e. [0,1,2,3,4,0] so the last line is the same as the first
        line = ""
        leadingSpaces = n-2-i
        line += " "*leadingSpaces
        line += "*"
        if i != 0:
            middleSpaces = 2*i-1
            line += " "*middleSpaces
            line += "*"
        print(line)


# Driver Code 
n = 5
Empty_triangle(n)
```

Comment: yes but last line star should be on the same position of first star in last line

Comment: @AHF i've edited the code. Is this looking more like what you want?

Comment: Though code is too direct but this output was my requirement. Thanks